# Are PCIe lanes dynamically assigned?

Tags: motherboard, gpu, pci-express, amd-ryzen

I want to use multiple GPUs on my motherboard ([Asus Crosshair Hero VII](https://www.asus.com/us/Motherboards/ROG-CROSSHAIR-VII-HERO/)) (CPU: [Ryzen 7 2700x](https://www.amd.com/en/products/cpu/amd-ryzen-7-2700x))

If I have 2 GPUs and use only the main one (x16) to do normal tasks, but use both for machine learning and 3D rendering, will the lanes be split dynamically?

In other words: If I run a task only on my main GPU, are all the 16 PCIe lanes be available to that GPU, or will they always stay split (8x for each GPU) without regard to the work load?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bad news first:

PCIe lanes are dynamic, but not the way you want: They are assigned (dynamically) at PCI configuration time, which is immediately after power on (if you ignore hot-plugable busses). Once the system is booting, there will be no more dynamic reallocation.

Now for the good news:

First of all it is very unlikely that you can saturate a Gen3 x16 PCIe bus with **any** AMD GPU in existance, not even an x8. The bottleneck will be the processing inside the card, not the data transfer via the bus - this ofcourse means, you will be very hard pressed to notice a difference.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the motherboard design.

If your motherboard does not have enough PCIe lanes (generally the case with recent Intel consumer CPUs or chipsets) then the motherboard will dynamically assign lanes; e.g.

```
X16           or       X8
unused                 X8
```

On the other hand, on Xeon motherboards, older intel boards (e.g. X55/Nehalem)
or AMD platforms the setup is typically more like this:

```
X16           or       X16
X16                    x8
x0                     x8
x8                     x8
x8                     x8
```

Notice the second pair which is the same x16/0 and x8/x8 combination

---

Now for your specific motherboard:

According the Asus website it supports: "2 x PCIe (x16 or dual x8)" (plus others)

I read that as:

```
X16           or       X8
unused                 X8
```

So you can use two graphics cards at x8. That is more than fast enough for just about any card. If you run two EUR1000+ cards then you might loose 2%-5% ish. But for anything up to regular high end cards PCI-e v3 x8 is more than enough.

Comment: It is now a few year later, but I have one important addition. When in doubt look for the term "PCI-e burification"